# What is the most performant way to remove "bad" values from an array, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to figure out which way is the best, in terms of performance.

Given the following problem;

**You have one array of numbers and another one with numbers you want to remove from the first array.**

I have tried a couple of things: https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/VRGgpm

```
let dataArray = [2,4,5,8,1,9,3];
let blackList = [3,5,8,7];

function findFaulty(data, bad) {
  if (bad.length > 0) {
    let cleanData = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
      let x = 0;
      bad.forEach(b => {
        if (b === item) return;
        x++;
        if (x >= bad.length) cleanData.push(item);
      });
    });
    return cleanData;  
  }
  return data;
};

console.log(findFaulty(dataArray, blackList));
```

Then: https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/GeXwBL?editors=0012

```
let dataArray = [2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 9, 3];
let blackList = [2, 3];

function filterData(data, bad) {
    bad.forEach((b, i, a) => a[i] = data.indexOf(b));
    bad.filter(x => x > -1).forEach((b, i) => data.splice(b, 1, -1));
    return data.filter(d => d > -1)
};

console.log(filterData(dataArray, blackList));
```

and finally: https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/EMdyVg

```
let data = [2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 9, 3];
let faulty = [2, 1, 5, 6];

let clean = data.filter(d => faulty.indexOf(d) < 0 );

console.log(clean);
```

Comment: Which one is most performant is something you need to test for the environment you want it to be most performant.

Comment: *filter* means new array, *remove* means same object reference without some items ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for making me aware. I was not properly thinking about this question. It makes totally sense though. It would depend on the production code, I guess. Can you please name a few scenarios where one would be better over the other?

Comment: @TheFool, actually i have no example, but it highly depends uns the use case.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the array from the end and splice found items.

```js
function filter(items, remove) {
    var i = items.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (remove.includes(items[i])) items.splice(i, 1);
    }
    return items;
}

console.log(...filter([2, 4, 5, 8, 1, 9, 3], [3, 5, 8, 7]));
```

Comment: That does not really answer the question. Is this better or worse in terms of performance to the one mention in the question? Which one performs best?

Comment: i was thinking of speed and less overhead as converting some parts, like the remocing items to a set or object. but the question is a bit unclear, should the original array returned or a filterd new one?

Comment: +1 It's the fastest when I run it, though jsperf isn't able to recognize the spread. https://jsperf.com/quick-removal-in-array/1

Comment: Nice, thanks. I was thinking about something like this but was missing the backwards part to make it work. A shrinking array size is a huge plus. 
I also thought if this were unique ID's, I could splice both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

With your existing data formats you can use filter and includes.

```js
let dataArray = [2,4,5,8,1,9,3];
let blackList = [3,5,8,7];

let op = dataArray.filter(e=> !blackList.includes(e))

console.log(op)
```

But IMO most performant way will be using `blackList` as object,

```js
let dataArray = [2,4,5,8,1,9,3];
let blackList = {3:false,5:false,8:false,7:false};

let op = dataArray.filter(e=> blackList[e] !== false)

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Just to point out, I ran some tests and the Object filter seems to be less performant than the  array filter.

Comment: @zfrisch - Probably only because the array is so tiny. Creating the object without a prototype would help too, or of course using a Map.

Comment: @zfrisch can i see those test ? and moreover IMO it will not be at all. as to find in array you need to iterate over each index which is `O(n)` and in `object` it is just `O(1)`

Comment: @CodeManiac https://jsperf.com/quick-removal-in-array/1

Comment: @zfrisch well as T.J it's because the size of arrays is small, you should try checking with different size and order of input